# PostgreSQL. Вывести все значения связанных ключей из двух JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, парсер

Есть в PostgreSQL таблица Tester с полями: id, date_test, fio, questions, results. В полях questions, results находятся, соответственно, анкета и результат в формате (jsonb).
JSON,хранящийся в поле Questions (в зависимости от теста может содержать разные количество секций):
{"id":"id1","name":"Тест","qSections":[{"id":"qsid1","ord":0,"name":"Группа 1","questions":[{"id":"qid1","name":"блаблабла","oSections":[{"id":"osid1","name":"блаблабла","qOptions":[{"id":"qoid1","value":"блаблабла"},{"id":"qoid2","value":"блаблабла"}]}]},{"id":"qid3","name":"блаблабла","oSections":[{"id":"oid4","name":"блаблабла","qOptions":[{"id":"qoid5","value":"блаблабла"},{"id":"qoid6","value":"блаблабла"},{"id":"qoid7","value":"блаблабла"}]}]},{"id":"id2","name":"блаблабла","oSections":[{"id":"osid2","name":"блаблабла","qOptions":[{"id":"qid2","value":"блаблабла'"},{"id":"qoid8","value":"блаблабла's"}]}]}]}]}
В вопросах может встречаться '.
Result:
Может быть пустым или содержать:
[{"id":"qoid1","value":"блаблабла"},{"id":"qoid3","value":null},{"id":"qoid5","value":12}],
где также могут быть пропущены ответы на вопросы или отвечены, но со значением null.

Нужно составить SELECT, выводящий всех пользователей, прошедших тест, дату, название теста и все ответы на вопросы (если не ответил на вопрос, то вывести "Нет ответа").

Есть мысль реализовать одним из способов:

1. С помощью WITH
2. Создать 2 вьюхи с анкетами и вопросами

Столкнулся со следующими проблемами:

1. Из анкеты выводится только первый вопрос
2. из ответов вообще ничего не выводится
3. Иногда ругается на "'" в JSON'ах

Код:

```
SELECT id, fio,
       a.questions::jsonb -> 'name'                            as name_survey,
       qSections ->> 'name'                                  AS qsections_name,
       qSections -> 'questions' -> 0 ->> 'id'              AS question_id,
       qSections -> 'questions' -> 0 ->> 'name'              AS question_name
FROM tester as a,
     jsonb_array_elements(a.questions -> 'qSections') qs(qSections)
order by a.questions::jsonb -> 'name', id; 

SELECT 
       results -> 'id' as ID,
       results -> 'value' AS value
FROM tester as a,
     jsonb_array_elements(a.results  -> '[{}]') pr(results);
```

С JSON в PostgreSQL раньше не работал. Что здесь не так? Как лучше написать запрос?